# Usuario con sql server atutenticacion no se conecta da error

Tags: sql-server

Quiero entrar con el usuario "fulano" con la autenticación de SQL server.. Pues resulta que sale un error y habilite al usuario y todo y en las propiedades-seguridad del servidor habilite la opción para conectarse por este tipo de autenticación pero aun así me sigue saliendo el error

[image: Imagen con el error]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

yo tenia el mismo problema y aqui encontre la solucion https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-user/

Comment: Muchas gracias gracias al link que compartiste he resuelto el problema :D

Comment: Hola Guaguazo, las publicaciones que son básicamente un enlace se consideran de baja calidad porque si el enlace se rompe, la respuesta deja de tener sentido. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para traer las partes claves de la página enlazada a la propia respuesta (manteniendo el enlace como referencia). Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Si la página desaparece o cambian el SEO, ese enlace ya no sirve y nadie sabrá cómo se resuelve el problema. Edita la respuesta e incluye lo más relevante para explicar cuál es la solución (o qué opciones se deben probar para resolverlo)